# C# real time graphing in a windows form application

Tags: c#, user-interface, graph, mschart, real-time-data

I am attempting to graph real time temperatures that are read using Modbus commands. Currently, I am able to read the temperature and graph it. However, once it draws the first point it does not continuously update the graph and GUI.

Should I be running this in a method other than `Form1_Load`?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.ChartAreas.Add("Area");
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisX.Minimum = -100;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisX.Maximum = 100;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisY.Minimum = -100;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisY.Maximum = 100;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisY.Interval = 1;

    //create a Data object array
    val[] data = new val[5];

    string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    this.comboBox1.DataSource = ports;
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM5";
    using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM5"))
    {
        //start time object
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        int startSec = start.Second;

        port.Open();
        byte slaveID = 1;
        ushort startAddress = 360;
        ushort numOfPoints = 2;
        ModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port);

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            ushort[] holding_register = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveID, startAddress,
            numOfPoints);

            ushort val1 = holding_register[0];
            ushort val2 = holding_register[1];

            uint t1 = (uint)(holding_register[0]);
            uint t2 = (uint)(holding_register[1] << 16);
            uint temp = (uint)(t1) | (t2);
            byte[] floatVals = BitConverter.GetBytes(temp);
            float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(floatVals, 0);
            c = 5.0 / 9.0 * (f - 32);

            textBox1.Text = c.ToString();

            DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
            int currentSec = current.Second;
            int time = currentSec - startSec;

            chart1.Refresh();

            data[j].time = time;
            data[j].temperature = c;

            chart1.Series[j].Points.Add(new DataPoint(data[j].time, data[j].temperature));

            chart1.Refresh();

            port.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a classic newb issue.  There is a designated UI thread in any windowed application.  It runs a message pump (that processes stuff like when a user clicks on the window), and is responsible for drawing the visual representation of the window.  You are doing work in the UI thread.  Normally, that's okay, but when you do LOTS of work in the UI thread, the UI thread can no longer run the message pump or draw the window. Your application appears to freeze, only updating when you are done.  This is why we do heavy work on *background threads* and transition to the UI thread to post updates.

Comment: Tons of resources out there like https://stuff.seans.com/2009/05/21/net-basics-do-work-in-background-thread-to-keep-gui-responsive/ or similar search results.

Comment: Where is your loop?

Comment: I would recommend running your code in a [backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) and using [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) to update your gui.  but as @TaW mentions, I don't see where your chart is updating.  Everytime your modbus event fires and comes back with data you should be updating your chart.

Answer (score 0):

Make your serial port a member variable, then add a timer to your form. You can then parse the serial data and append data points to your graph inside the timer callback.